# How should I train to increase my push-up maximum from 20 to two sets of 100?

Tags: training, push-ups, pull-ups

I hope this question is not considered off topic because my honour is on the line here. A few ago, my friend called me a "lightweight" for not being able to do as many push-ups as him. So I challenged him to competition where the person that can do two sets of 100 push-ups by the end of February wins and the person that loses has to run until they puke. Currently, I can do about 20 push-ups. I am considering doing the 7-week "100 push-ups" regimen along with the "7 weeks to 50 pull ups" program. Do you think this is the best way to win or do you think that there is a better way I can win?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: See if [this](http://hundredpushups.com/) helps. Also check this [question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9411/100-push-up-i-went-from-36-to-28-after-being-sick-is-it-normal-how-can-i-impr).

Comment: How many push-ups can you do now? Do you work out or play sports?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I can do about 20 pushups right now and I do play sports occasionally.

Comment: Now a days i can't able to do a single pushup.. :( i can't able to balance my weight while pushup is there any warmup's..?

Comment: @VivekVikranth There are loads of push-up variations. If your major issue is balance then an easier variant such as doing them from your knees or simply spreading your legs out might be sufficient.

Comment: @VivekVikranth That would be a good question for you to post.

Comment: @JeelShah: How did the challenge go?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann You were right when you said "someone's going to drop out before December, or everyone involved is a little juvenile". I dropped out, uncharacteristically, in December. However, I am currently following your plan and my progress is quite nice and I hope to achieve my goal. I am currently, again, in the first phase. Out of curiosity, do you think I should do some push ups on off days?

Comment: @JeelShah I think off-days are a good time to take a walk, or do some yoga, or work on mobility. But push-ups are a good second-tier option too, as long as they don't interfere with the training days.

Comment: Other than walking and yoga, what are some other things you can do to improve mobility?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The end of February is twenty weeks away](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how%20many%20weeks%20are%20there%20from%20now%20until%20the%20end%20of%20february%202014). With that much time until the competition, you should periodize your training into a general preparation, specific training, and competition lead-up. Doing just push-ups might work too, but you will achieve better results with a more balanced approach.

### General preparation - 6 weeks

For the general preparation phase, you should consider your cardiovascular ability, your level of strength, and your joint mobility. If any of these are pathological, it would make sense to deal with that issue. If you're average in each of these, then the general approach I'd use is to do some cardio and strength training each week. [This program](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/13427/1771), or any of the others on that page, would be fine. I'd make room at the beginning and end of each workout to do at least a few sets of push-ups.

So in this stage, in order to get yourself generally ready for physical competition, you would do something like this, three times a week:

> - Warm up with a quick jog or stationary bike, plus a set or two of push-ups to near-failure
> - Bench press, 3 sets of 12, heavy, with a spotter or dumbbells
> - Some kind of squat (air, goblet, barbell, dumbbell, kettlebell), two sets of five
> - Pull-ups, three sets to failure (with good form)
> - Deadlifts, one set of five to ten, heavy
> - Short cardio finisher (unless you want to do this, or a longer cardio session, on non-lifting days), such as two or three 100m sprints or 5 minutes of a barbell or kettlebell complex
> - Two sets of push-ups to failure

I would do yoga, particularly Down Dog and Sun Salutations peppered with push-ups, every day or at least on off days. Be careful with jumping in too quickly to this training, however, lest you get injured. Take it easy the first week, a little less easy the second and third weeks, then push yourself hard in the fourth week and beyond.

### Specific preparation - 6 weeks

After six weeks of getting yourself generally fit and strong, it's time to narrow your training towards push-ups while still developing qualities like whole-body strength and endurance. I would focus on short-to-medium cardio efforts (which broadly match the timing of 200 pushups) and upper-body strength (which is closely related to your push-up goal). Of course I would continue with the push-ups. So, six weeks of:

> - Warm up with a quick jog or stationary bike
> - Five sets of 25+ push-ups each, **not** to failure, alternated with front and side planks, push-up variations (wide, narrow, staggered), uneven push-ups using a ball or stack of books on one side, and so on
> - Pull-ups, three sets of one-half your maximum (or if that's less than 3, then 5, using negatives), to balance the pressing work
> - Bench press, 3 heavy sets of 10--make sure you use dumbbells or have a spotter
> - Either squat or deadlift, light
> - Supplemental pressing work: dips, three sets to failure

Of course, I would be trying to increase the weight on the bar each week for the bench press. On off days, I would go for a jog and then do at least two hundred total push-ups. The five sets should be totaling around or over two hundred.

### Competition preparation - eight weeks

In the final lead-up to the test, I would keep doing one general workout per week up until four weeks out: bench press, dips, a little squatting/deadlifting/pull-upping. At least once a week, I'd test myself: two sets of push-ups to failure, of at least fifty each, shooting for 110 or 120. All my other workouts would be specific to the competition, and I'd have at least three of them. Something like one of the following:

> - Four or five hundred total push-ups
> - Pyramids with short rest times, starting at 10 and adding one each set until you get to 20
> - A set of push-ups, then run a quarter mile (or do burpees, or otherwise make yourself exhausted), then another set of push-ups without stopping
> - Working with diamond push-ups and wide push-ups

You should aim to be exceeding your goal by the end of January, with four weeks to spare. At that point I'd drop the general workouts entirely and just keep working on long sets of push-ups. The last week before the competition I'd barely work out at all, just rest.

### Other approaches

The plan I outlined above is rough and should be taken as a template, not a specialized plan. It is meant to show the broad strokes of a plan: get strong and fit while doing push-ups, then get really good at pushing motions, then get awesome at push-ups. You could match those broad strokes with other approaches, too. For instance:

- Four times a week, run for a mile then do a circuit of push-ups, pull-ups, and air squats. Each month increase the number of push-ups you do, but keep everything else constant. Start doing extra sets of clap push-ups, one-arm push-ups, super-slow and super-fast push-ups. In the third month, run a shorter distance and do fewer pull-ups and squats. In the last month, just warm up and do push-ups exactly like you will for the competition.

...or:

- Spend a month training yoga daily at a studio, to get your shoulders and back limber. Do push-ups at home at least three times a week. Then spend two months with dumbbells, doing high-rep bench presses, rows, and squats, finishing each workout with four sets of push-ups to failure, using a different push-up variation in each one. In the last month, stop lifting and just do huge numbers of regular push-ups every weekday.

...or:

- Join a gym and do a whole-body circuit on the machines, five days a week. Finish each workout with five sets of push-ups and a short jog. After two months, cut the number of exercises in the circuit in half and double the number of push-ups. In the last month, just warm up and do every kind of push-up you can think of for ninety minutes.

The point is, you have plenty of time to get your entire body ready. You don't want to overtrain or get injured. So yes, absolutely do a lot of push-ups. But don't neglect other methods of getting strong, like dips and bench press, and don't forget to keep your shoulders, back, and chest healthy with pulling exercises and overhead work.

### Perspective

Remember, this competition is dumb. In particular, the part about "run until you puke" tells me that either someone's going to drop out before December, or everyone involved is a little juvenile. Go ahead and win it, but do it by making yourself awesome instead of valuing foolish grandstanding.

### Really?

A skeptic might justifiably ask, "why do anything other than push-ups to prepare for a push-up contest?" The justification comes from experiments in sport science, which have found that general physical preparation will provide a greater and more effective training stimulus than just the target activity itself. Without putting too much credence in the exercises/sets/reps of this specific proposal, it's a well understood athletic principle that just doing the specific thing that will be tested is rarely the optimal approach for non-elite athletes. When there's time, a periodized approach of `general -> specific -> competition prep` produces best results.

You'll see this in many sports. For instance, in running (except for extreme-distance runs like ultra-marathons), a little strength and speed work early in the season is better than just running. The same is found in football, powerlifting, judo, and so on. Squats and deadlifts (programmed with less intensity, priority, and volume than the multiple forms of pressing work) produce an enormous training effect in the novice. They develop core strength and the ability to exert maximum force that will stave off injury and--yes--improve one's ability to do large numbers of push-ups.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the details and layout. This is really comprehensive. In the first six weeks, when it says "pull-ups" how many do I do? Is that up to me? Is that also the same for the push-ups? Also, what does "short cardio finisher" mean? and "short to medium cardio efforts", what does that involve?

Comment: I edited to add my answers to your first four questions. "Short to medium" means anything from a sprint (<30 second all-out effort) to something like running a mile or two (up to 10 or 15 minutes of moderate effort). Really it means "cardio, but not a long slow slogging run". Bear in mind that while I wrote all this up, I'm no authority on push-up training or physical fitness in general. It's just the gist of what I would do.

Comment: The asker's goal is to maximise push-ups and you recommend *squats* and *deadlifts*??

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Yes. As stated, he has plenty of time for general physical preparation, which will provide a greater and more effective training stimulus than the activity itself. I might be wrong in this specific application of the principle, and I wouldn't put too much credence in the exercises/sets/reps of this specific plan, but it's a well understood athletic principle that just doing the specific thing that will be tested is rarely the optimal approach for non-elite athletes. When there's time, a periodized approach of general-specific-competition prep produces greater results.

Comment: You'll see this in many sports. For instance, running (except for extreme-distance runs like ultramarathons), where a little strength and speed work early in the season is better than just running. It's the same in powerlifting, judo, and so on. Squats and deadlifts (programmed with less intensity, priority, and volume than the multiple forms of pressing work) produce an enormous training effect in the novice. They develop core strength and the ability to exert maximum force that will stave off injury and--yes--improve his ability to do large numbers of push-ups.

Comment: I got this from general reading including Dan John and Pavel Tsatsouline, but particularly Tom Kurz' Science of Sports Training. Four months of push-ups and nothing else is overkill. Six weeks of light push-up work alongside general strength, mobility, and endurance training, followed by six weeks with an emphasis on pressing strength and moderate push-up work, followed by eight weeks of push-ups galore, is plenty of push-up-specific training.

Comment: +1 for "Go ahead and win it, but do it by making yourself awesome instead of valuing foolish grandstanding". Nice job of pointing the OP in a better direction.

Comment: But what if foolish grandstanding is the only reason you work out? :(

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr That's common, and my advice for that situation is to at least direct the foolish grandstanding to a routine that's going to be good for you in general as well as satisfy your vanity or ego.

Comment: I have seen that finding out the weak points while doing push ups and training it improves the ability to do more push ups.For example my shoulders and abs.

Answer (score 3):

**If your goal is to be able to maximise the number of push-ups you can do by February, I'd recommend doing lots of push-ups.**

Seriously. If that is your only goal (and there are worse goals), just **do lots of push-ups**. Just push-ups. All the time, **only push-ups**. So unless they are part of the challenge, no pull-ups - **just push-ups**.

Probably the best way to go about this is [the "grease the groove" method](http://www.leanandmuscular.org/greasing-the-groove.php). The gist of it is, do an exercise (usually a bodyweight exercise) to well before exhaustion, several times a day, several times a week. As the link states

> For example, lets say you can usually do 10 pull-ups with good form. What you’d then do is perform 5-8 reps (50-80% of your best/max) 4-6 times per day, 4-6 times per week.

The goal behind this thinking is:

> As the movement becomes easier and more natural, you will be able to do more and more reps. You can then GRADUALLY start adding more weight/resistance to keep the exercise challenging.

Aim to add about 5 push-ups per week to each set, or about 1 per session.

Set one day a week as your "challenge day" to do as many push-ups as you can, in a single set, to complete failure. Do it early in the day though, because you need the rest of the day to rest, because tomorrow - **you're doin' push-ups**.

Comment: If you go this way, enjoy the hunchback build that comes from just doing chest workouts...

Comment: @andrewb I ain't saying its a good way to build muscle or aesthetics. But the OP wanted to know how to be able to do 200 push-ups. Also, once they hit about 20 in a set, its more of an endurance exercise and less of a hypertrophy one. Kind of like why marathoners don't have huge legs.

Comment: @LegoStormtrooper Do we really want to be advocating non-holistic fitness? This proposed regime would eventually lead to some muscle problems. Also as you said, it becomes more of an endurance exercise - this makes cross-training more viable. Like some front crawl swimming.

Comment: @andrewb Would it lead to problems? Push-up have been a staple as both exercise and punishment in most militaries for a while. They aren't perfect, but people have had to do upwards of 200 push-ups a day and aren't falling apart. As for advocating non-holistic fitness, thats more tough - what qualifies as non-holistic? Running without strength training, vice versa?

Comment: @LegoStormtrooper I've always been taught the importance of training both directions of motion/opposite muscle groups. I really think this should be coupled with horizontal pull ups. From what I've seen from athletes, the best way for them to boost a specialised activity often involves a broader range of activities. Balanced exercise is probably what I mean by holistic. Lifting isn't a must, but I'd say balanced muscle conditioning is.